# How to Make another column mandatory based on a value set in another column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in Excel.

```
Value1   Value2
Yes      This become mandatory
No       Then Optional
```

so if the value1 column has Yes then Value2 should become mandatory else it can stay empty.
The user should not be allowed to save the sheet if the col1 has yes and col2 is empty.

Comment: Anything is fine ..either the formula or the VBA as long as it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [Data Validation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010072600.aspx).

On Value2, set the "Allow" criterion to Custom, and then set the Formula to `=OR(Value1<>"Yes",NOT(ISBLANK(Value2)))`. That way, if Value1 is set to Yes, Excel won't let the user clear Value2.

You can also set the same criterion for Value1. Then, the user can only enter "Yes" there if there's already something in Value2.

Comment: It says " A named range you specified cannot be found "

Comment: @SandeepYadav, replace Value1 and Value2 with the actual cell addresses of those values, e.g. A1 and B1. Alternatively, right-click the each column, select "Name a Range," and name it.

Comment: But I want to do that for the entire column and not for each. How do I apply this for the entire column. Also, I dont see the Name a range option when i right click on the columns

Comment: @SandeepYadav, If you apply the data validation to the top cell in the column and then copy down, it will apply to lower cells, with the cells in the formula automatically kept consistent, just like copying and pasting a cell formula.

Comment: I am able to apply the same formula for all the cells, but the sheet is still allowing save when value2 column has empty cells in it.

Comment: @SandeepYadav, I'm not sure how to prevent saving. You might indeed need VBA to kick in in the OnSave event, or something, and check all the cells. If that's what you want to do, (as opposed to validating data as it's entered, which I've showed you how to do), you should make that clear in your question, or perhaps another question.